# Display values from foreign key in Django Admin

Tags: python, django

I am trying to show values from a foreign key in my model value (in admin).

I am using "except" tho I am I should use explicit. How do I use this? And how to I get the below working correctly? It just shows (none) but there is a value there.

Thanks

Admin.py

```
----------------------
    def price(self, obj):
        try:
            price = Price.objects.filter(variation=Variation.objects.filter(product=obj)[0])
        except:
            price = 'None'
        return format_html('<center><b>"{0}"</b></center>', price.price)
```

Models.py

```
--------

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField ("Name", max_length=130)
    link = models.URLField("Link", max_length=740)

class Variation(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, blank=False, null=False)
    variation = models.CharField (max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.variation

class Price(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField("Price", decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    variation = models.ForeignKey(Variation, blank=False, null=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    def __int__(self):
        return self.price
```

Comment: Shouldn't be: ``return format_html('<center><b>"{0}"</b></center>', price.price)`` ?

Comment: You should know that the Django ORM creates related fields for ForeignKey back-references. You should try `my_product.variation_set` on a `Product` instance. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects for details!

Comment: There are many variations for a product, and many prices for a variation. Which do you want to show?

Comment: Oh- I see the issue. Can I just return the first variable by default? Or can I preset a variable called "default" for it to return? I have used this 'unconventoinal' method to do a similar thing with another field -     def admin_image(self, obj):
        try:
            url = Image.objects.filter(variation=Variation.objects.filter(product=obj)[0])[0]
        except:
            url = 'None'
        return format_html('<center><a href="{0}" target="_blank"><img src="{1}"/width="100px"></a></center>',
                           *((url, )*2))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to simplify your code.

Instead:

```
price = Price.objects.filter(variation=Variation.objects.filter(product=obj)[0])
```

You can write:

```
price = Price.objects.filter(variation__product=obj)
```

Filter return QuerySet, but You want to have one price:

```
price = Price.objects.filter(variation__product=obj)[0]
```

When no price found, You want to write `None`, else price.price:

```
try:
    price = Price.objects.filter(variation__product=obj)[0].price
except Price.DoesNotExist:
    price = 'None'
return format_html('<center><b>"{0}"</b></center>', price)
```

And finally "explicit" version:

```
prices = Price.objects.filter(variation__product=obj)
price = prices[0].price if prices.exists() else 'None'
return format_html('<center><b>"{0}"</b></center>', price)
```

Comment: Thank you- I was told "except" can cause memory/hardwares issues- and to use explicit instead. How would this be applied? Would this be better/safer? `except ValueError:
            pass`